# show form php if statement true

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

```
<?php
        if($dun==0){
     show form1 and add vaules to database
         }
        else if($toplam==0){
 show form2 and add values to database
    }
        else if($toplam==$dun){
        header('Location: member.php');
         }else{
        echo "<script> alert('Error.');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
        ?>
```

How i can show two different from by the if statement

Comment: What is `$dun` and what is `$toplam`?

Comment: $dun a value from database and $toplam is a price comes from another form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use inline HTML by closing the `<?PHP` tag with `?>` like this:

```
<?php
if($dun==0){
// start parsing HTML
?>
    <form>[...]</form>
<?PHP
} else if($toplam==0){
// start parsing second HTML
?>
    <form>[...]</form>
<?PHP
}
else if($toplam==$dun){
    header('Location: member.php');
}else{
    echo "<script> alert('Error.');history.go(-1);</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this is what i need i will try and come back Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If OOP is not used and you are unfamiliar with OOP programming and MVC framework or html rendering then you could do the following:

```
form1.php file holds the HTML for form 1
form2.php file holds the HTML for form 2

if ($dun == 0) {
    include('form1.php');
//add values to database
} else if ($toplam == 0) {
    include('form2.php');
//add values to database
}
```

Comment: I have no idea about OOP and MVC im working with php mysql and html

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just `echo` the forms the same way you `echo'd` the `javascript`?

```
<?php
        if($dun==0){
          echo '
             <form name="form1"><input type="submit" name="submit1" /></form>
          ';
         }
        else if($toplam==0){
          echo '
             <form name="form2"><input type="submit" name="submit2" /></form>
          ';
         }
        else if($toplam==$dun){
            header('Location: member.php');
         }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Error.');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
?>
```

And if you wanted to insert data into your database depending on the `if` statements then you could add `functions`:

```
<?php

  function doForm1(){
     //MYSQL HERE
  }

  function doForm2(){
     //MYSQL HERE
  }

        if($dun==0){
          echo '
             <form name="form1"><input type="submit" name="submit1" /></form>
          ';
          doForm1();
         }
        else if($toplam==0){
          echo '
             <form name="form2"><input type="submit" name="submit2" /></form>
          ';
          doForm2();
         }
        else if($toplam==$dun){
            header('Location: member.php');
         }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Error.');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: That's alright bud, let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: I have used @Luceos solution way and worked perfect for me thank you for all

Comment: Click the `tick` on his answer :)